# Resuming data from a database is extra slow - VBA

Tags: excel, database, vba, performance

So, i've got a Workbook that will have more than 1500 rows of data in it's database... That's... not much, it is very fast to run that;

I'll have to make a resumed table of the data, but the user will have to choose some of the filters for the table, there are three major things that will have to happen:

1st the user will select an  "OT" (That's the name the company gives to their clients, OTXXXXXX), that will have to trigger some vba code which will preset a table

2nd There will be a 3 row header, with some very simple formula in the last header's last 2 rows and the first will be the products of that client

3rd Now we are f****, the rows part will have a "header"(Is that the name?) with a 1 column width, but that little, not so little, sh**, has around 140 rows plus with invoices, and for each Invoice x Product cell there will be a number of boxes that went off

Now, i´ve already tried doing it "manually" on VBA, reading each cell's row and column, getting the references, going to DB and bringing back the number of boxes, an i7 9750H with 16Gb of ram disliked that, so I'm not able to give that to the company (their Desktops runs way slower than my laptop). So i´ve tried to use a formula to do that, I've tryed an array formula and a matrix formula, both worked meh, around 2-3 min of processing, which would translate to 8-10min it´s fine... Buuuut the database keeps increasing and each change on it triggers the calculation, and disabling it would be even worse..., I can't afford that time loss, so i'm litterally lost.

I don't know what to do, just help

Please  ;-;

Comment: Always helps to show what code or formula you are using. Otherwise it's basically impossible to provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: Well, i've tried a pivot table, it works, but... anyone has any sugestions on how to make it easier for the user? (They know basically nothing about excel)

Comment: We can't help, because we don't have your spreadsheet. We need a [reprex] in order to propose an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You may divide them in more execution threads. Also, check that database to be correctly built. Check every connection you use to be sure it work. For 1.500 rows 8 mins it's too much.

Comment: "You may divide them in more execution threads." No. This is not how Excel works. Unfortunately this is a case of "database in Excel" - which I cringe at.

Comment: I am sorry I thought it's actually a DB. Why don't you move to a serious DB. It gives you more flexibility.

Comment: Well that's what I would do - but it's not my data :)

Comment: In execution of Excel that may be way too heavy when big data appear. I recommand MySQL or Oracle. Also you can easily export all the data with 2-3 clicks to a dedicated DB.

Comment: I am not the asker of the original question by the way :)

Comment: I can't use a normal database, simply that, the company runs on Excel, I know it's bad, but there's no reason to be cinical @BigBen.
Adrian, I'd love to move it to a more usable database, but, for that it would be a whole software development, not just a spreadsheet improvement, which is what the company wants (besides, they're not willing to afford more than what they already spend on the Excel improvments now...)

Comment: Not meant to be taken as cynical, often I'm in the same spot @AlexSilva. I share your frustration.